# Getting rtmp link from youtube android sdk

Tags: android, youtube-api, rtmp, android-youtube-api

I want to stream on youtube using rtmp. Is there any way I can get rtmp link like we get from facebook api ?

Comment: I don't think that youtube provides RTMP streams

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no mention of getting RTMP links in [Livestreams](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams#resource) under Youtube API. The only mention of rtmp was in `cdn.ingestionType` property as a way to transmit the video stream.